# Do I need two copies of MindFeud on the 3DS to play multiplayer?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, mindfeud

I was looking at [MindFeud](https://www.nintendo.co.uk/Games/Nintendo-3DS-download-software/Mindfeud-941331.html) for the 3DS and one of the features was:

> Invite friends or complete strangers and battle online

Does that mean I have one copy of the game, I can play with a friend who does not have the game (similar to how MarioKart works?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mindfeud is Internet only for its multiplayer, so each player must have their own copy.

I [asked Engine Software directly](https://twitter.com/EngineSoftware/status/550037717065932800) to get this answer.